# Best database to use for business routing workflows

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I'm looking to create a database for a CAPA (corrective action/preventive action form).  Basically, one person creates the initial report.  This is forwarded on to the CAPA manager, who fills out another field on the form.  Then it goes to the investigator, who fills out some information.  Then it goes back to the CAPA manager and so forth.

My instinct is to create an Access frontend with a SQL Server backend.  I'd need to kick off an e-mail at each step of the process.  I'd also need to send reminder e-mails if it gets stale for X days at any of the stages.

I know I could really accomplish this with most databases out there, but my main question is, is there any database or third party product out there that would make the process of setting up that routing workflow easier?  I have other projects where the routing would be similar to the one above or an approval workflow.

Comment: E-mailing every time something happens is usually a bad idea. When getting spammed by a system people start using filters and ignoring it. It's better to have a single location where someone can see every action they have to take and e-mail them _once_ if they ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it is absolutely possible to implement this project with proposed technologies.

If your company already has adopted SharePoint 2010 it can be also good option for implementing collaborative work flows.

Also from my experience MS Access works best if connection to server is stable like intranet.